# Return multiple values based on duplicate max values in another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to summarise a df by group using multiple functions. Replication data:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(a=c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'), b=c(1,NA,3,2,2,1), c=c(1,3,5,5,2,4))
```

One of these is a custom function that asks for the value of `df1$b` when `max(df1$c)` in each group (`df1$a`). When the result is `NA`, it should return the value for `df1$b` for the second-highest value of `df1$c`. The following works:

```
namax <- function(x,y) ifelse(is.na(y[x==max(x)] & length(x)>1),
                              y[x==sort(x,partial=length(x)-1)[length(x)-1]], y[x==max(x)])
```

I then try to summarise `df1` using:

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  dplyr::group_by(a) %>%
  summarise(meanc = mean(c),
            maxc = namax(c,b))
```

Which returns the following, because for `df$a == 'b'` the max value of `df1$c` occurs twice for different values of `df1$b`.

> Error: Column 'maxc' must be length 1 (a summary value), not 2

Is there an elegant solution through which dplyr returns both values, while simultaneously executing the other call to `summarise()` (e.g. by adding `do()` to the call to `group_by`)? In my applied case I am trying to run several different calls to `summarise`, aside from the one using the `namax` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the values in a list, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

 df1 %>%
     group_by(a) %>%
     summarise(meanc = mean(c),
               maxc = list(namax(c, b)))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  a     meanc maxc     
#  <fct> <dbl> <list>   
#1 a         2 <dbl [1]>
#2 b         5 <dbl [2]>
#3 c         3 <dbl [1]>
```

You can use `unnest()` to expand,

```
df1 %>%
     group_by(a) %>%
     summarise(meanc = mean(c),
               maxc = list(namax(c, b))) %>% 
     unnest()

# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  a     meanc  maxc
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 a         2     1
#2 b         5     3
#3 b         5     2
#4 c         3     1
```